# Align line labels parallel to each segment of polygon offset from opposite ends

Tags: qgis, field-calculator

I have a polygon layer which I need to label on the opposite ends of a line and still maintain the labels parallel to this segment of a polygon. The labels need to be offset slightly from the end point of the line segment. In order to achieve this, I have derived lines that make up a polygon and now am struggling to achieve the desired labelling effect. I have used function `$x_at( -1)`. How can I label it to be identical to

[image]

where I have the lines making up a polygon as

[image]

Comment: If you are starting from lines, you may use something like `x(line_interpolate_point($geometry,0.7*$length))` for the X coordinate and `y(line_interpolate_point($geometry,0.7*$length))` for the Y coordinate. It essentially places your label at a specific percentage of the total length of the line feature (in this example, 70%).

Comment: Once you start using data defined setting how then do you set the placement to be aligned parallel?

Comment: Did the trick work for you? If yes, I could add an answer (starting from line features)

Comment: in terms of placing the labels at opposite ends it works, But they not parallel to the line segment of the polygon

Comment: For parallelism use: -angle_at_vertex ($ geometry, 0) +90